# Make a change to thousands of subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, powershell

Office 365 admin here.

Our office manager contracted out our sharepoint development and now we IT helpdesk guys are on the hook to fix what they didn't get right. I didn't get to this position by being a go-getter so I'm looking to write a script or batch file to seek and make the required changes. Beats going one by one and making each change.

Basically we are organized by department. Accounting has it's own site, Operations has it's own site. Under the operation's site, we are organized by job number. Call it Job-0001 through Job-9999. Each Job-XXXX has it's own subsite.

The dev forgot to make the change in each subsite from UTC+10:00 Guam to UTC-5:00 EST. We've been tasked to go to each of the thousands of jobs and change them manually on our down time [subsite > site contents > regional settings > time zone]. It seems that we are not able to make this change from the "Operations" site level.

Additionally there are some view changes that everyone has decided would work better, mainly heading into each sub site and going through [settings > edit view > sort by > document type] to get a standard view when opening any subsite.

I have an obvious range that I could apply these changes to as Sharepoint generates the URLs based on the titles of the subsites. I'm just not sure how to easily create something that can send the updates up the cloud to alleviate hundreds of hours of work.

So I guess I'm looking for a while loop to start

```
While JOBNUMBER < 10,000  
{

(Top)

Goto JOBNUMBER's regional settings page

make the time UTC-5:00 EST 

update the server side

goto JOBNUMBER's edit view page

set the "first sort by the column" field to "document type" 

update the server side

(JOBNUMBER + 1 = JOBNUMBER)

Return to top

}
```

I'm curious on what platform I should start pursuing these changes. I have extremely limited experience coding anything other than hello world & I'm not sure if there is an easy way to interface the changes above.

Where would you recommend I start?

Thanks for the read,

Matt

Comment: The answer is most likely going to be PowerShell, and probably the "Patterns and Practices" cmdlet library. https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices